# Applications crashes in 3.0 but works fine in 2.3.3

Tags: android, sockets, android-3.0-honeycomb

Hi guys im trying to create a application that uses a socket connection i was going across some examples, the piece of code below works fine when i run it on 2.3.3 and the same crashes in 3.0.

```
package com.simple.client;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SimpleClientActivity extends Activity {
EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Socket socket = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

try {
 socket = new Socket("172.16.2.172", 8899);
 dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
 textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
 if (socket != null){
  try {
   socket.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 if (dataOutputStream != null){
  try {
   dataOutputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 if (dataInputStream != null){
  try {
   dataInputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}};
}
```

I have tried all but not able to figure out what is happening,

Comment: you should post you error stack trace, but I'm guessing you're getting NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: 1st guess goes to **NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Comment: Is that exception specific for a Android 3.0

Comment: It is specific for newer versions of Android (Honeycomb and up)

Comment: Please post some logs. It will help people avoid blind guesses :)

Comment: I tried to catch networkonMainThreadException and it got caught and how can i handle it now.

Comment: can you debug? where does it crash? can you post stack trace?

Comment: maybe your crash is in onCreate(). put its content in try-catch

Comment: The exception NetworkOnMainThreadException  is being caught at socket = new Socket("172.16.2.172", 8899); in the onClick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, the error caused by [StrictMode.ThreadPolicy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html). In android 3.0, you can't access network in the same UI thread.

Comment: Got it friend just had to add these lines in my code.                   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple resource folders for your layouts? if yes, maybe you do not have its related layout.

Comment: No i dont have separate layout folders for portrait and landscape